# Is it possible to alter part of a variable based on its value?

Tags: powershell

I have a script that grabs a list of AD usernames for members of a student group and allocates those as an array of $students

Later the script will need to take those usernames and input them into a URL

```
$students = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "GG_LHS All Students" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SamAccountName | Sort-Object SamAccountName

foreach ($student in $students)
{
    foreach ($OneDriveAdmin in $OneDriveAdmins)
Set-SPOUser -Site https://mydomain-my.sharepoint.com/personal/$($student)_mydomain_co_uk
```

In the cases where we have duplicate usernames, our naming scheme adds increments in the format of .1 and .2, but I need to change the ".1" to a "_1" to work in the URL.

My initial thinking is an IF statement during the $students declaration
`IF SamAccountName is like '.1' replace '.1' with '_1'`

Is this possible to do via powershell?

Comment: You have samAccountNames in AD with a dot followed by a digit/s ?

Comment: Yes. This was always the naming scheme from well before I started.

Comment: The idea is to replace jbloggs.1 with jbloggs_1 so that it will work when called in the URL

Comment: As an aside: Remove `SamAccountName` from your `Sort-Object` call: your inputs are _strings_, due to use of `Select-Object -ExpandProperty`, so they must be sorted _themselves_ (they have no `SamAccountName` property).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To offer a streamlined alternative to [Santiago Squarzon's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71527792/45375), using the (also regex-based) 
[`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) operator:

```
# Sample student account names
$students = 'jdoe.1', 'jsixpack', 'jroe.2'

# Transform all names, if necessary, and loop over them.
foreach ($student in $students -replace '\.(?=\d+$)', '_') {
  $student
}
```

<sup>Regex notes: `\.` matches a verbatim `.`, and `(?=...)` is a look-ahead assertion that matches one or more (`+`) digits (`\d`) at the end (`$`) of the string. What the look-ahead assertion matches doesn't become part of the overall match, so it is sufficient to replace only the `.` char.</sup>

Output:

```
jdoe_1
jsixpack
jroe_2
```

Note:

- `-replace` - like `-match` accepts an *array* as its LHS, in which case the operation is performed on *each element*, and a (usually transformed) new array is returned.
- If the regex on the RHS in a given replacement operation *doesn't match*, the input string is *passed through* (returned as-is), so it is safe to attempt replacement on strings that don't match the pattern of interest.

Answer (score 3):

You could add this check in your loop, if student matches a dot followed by any amount of digits (`\.(\d+)`), replace for the same digits but prepending and underscore instead (`-replace $Matches[0], "_$($Matches[1])"`):

```
foreach($student in $students) {
    if($student -match '\.(\d+)$') {
        $student = $student -replace $Matches[0], "_$($Matches[1])"
    }

    # rest of your code here
}
```

See https://regex101.com/r/fZAOur/1 for more info.